# Create array with hibernate SQLQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, unnest

i have this sql which works on my postgres database

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c']) LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'x') a ON (true)
```

now i want to use it in my hibernate application

```
    String[] enumStrings = EnumUtils.getEnumMap(Language.class).keySet().toArray(new String[]{});
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[:languages]) LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'x') a ON (true) ";
    SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setParameterList("languages", enumStrings);
    List result = query.list();
```

but i get an exception

```
a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

any ideas how to recostruct my query with a hibernate SQLQuery?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ... ON true` looks like simple `CROSS JOIN`. `SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c']) CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'x') a(col_name)`

Comment: Second you probably need to build array and pass it as parameter `SELECT * FROM  unnest(?) ...` or try: `SELECT * FROM unnest(string_to_array(?,',')) ...`